# Bug with saving editing item in table-list

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have marketing "campaign" in application.

There is also table of all campaigns which user can edit.

After editing campaign and click Save there in table of campaign appear duplication of that campaign.

After refresh the page that duplication of campaign disappears.

**That means** there is duplicate of campaign which is not saved in database, only in that table (list) which after refreshing page disappears.

Expected result: On save editing campaign there shouldn't appear duplication of campaign.

Does someone have some idea what can be the problem?

Here is typescript file of list component:

```
export class NanoCampaignListComponent implements OnChanges {

@Input() advertiserId: string;
@Input() advertiserIoId: string;
@Input() insertionOrderTargeting: string;

// public advertiserId: string;
// public advertiserIoId: string;
public campaignListDto: CampaignListDto;
public campaignListDtoData: CampaignListDtoData;
public columnsArray = TABLE_COLUMNS;

private subscription: Subscription;

constructor(private campaignModel: CampaignModel,
            private modalModel: ModalModel,
            private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    // this.subscribeToRouteParamsChange();
}

public ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.getListDto();
    this.getListDtoData();
}

public getCampaignModel(): CampaignModel {
    return this.campaignModel;
}

// public ngOnDestroy() {
//     this.subscription.unsubscribe();
// }

public openModal(id: string): void {
    const data = {
            id: id,
            advertiserId: this.advertiserId,
            insertionOrderId: this.advertiserIoId,
            insertionOrderTargeting: this.insertionOrderTargeting
        };
    this.modalModel.add(CampaignModel.ENTITY_NAME, data);
}

private getListDto(): void {
    this.campaignListDto = this.campaignModel.getListDto(this.advertiserIoId);
    // this.campaignListDto = this.campaignModel.getListDto(this.advertiserId);
}

private getListDtoData(): void {
    this.campaignModel
        .getListDtoData(this.campaignListDto)
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

Here is the **INITIAL** list component.html for table:

```
<div class="nano-f nano-f-c">

<div class="nano-f-40 nano-f-r">
    <nano-add-new-button class="nano-bc-yellow hover-effect" (click)="openModal('new')">
    </nano-add-new-button>
</div>

<nano-table *ngIf="campaignListDto.isLoaded === true"
            [@fadeIn]="'in'"
            [tableList]="campaignListDto.list"
            [columnsArray]="columnsArray"
            [pageCount]="5"
            [sortField]="'impressions'"
            [sortInverse]="true">
    <ng-template let-campaignListDtoData="item">
        <div class="nano-table-entity-name-cell">
            <span [tooltip]="campaignListDtoData.name"
                  [routerLink]="['/private/advertiser/' + advertiserId + + '/advertiserIo/' + advertiserIoId +'/campaign/' + campaignListDtoData.id]"
                  class="nano-c-p">
                {{ campaignListDtoData.name }}
            </span>
            <span>
                {{ campaignListDtoData.id }}
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="nano-table-number-cell">
            <span>
                {{ campaignListDtoData.revenue | number:'.2-2' }}
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="nano-table-number-cell">
            <span>
                {{ campaignListDtoData.cost | number:'.2-2' }}
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="nano-table-number-cell">
            <span>
                {{ campaignListDtoData.impressions | number }}
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="nano-table-number-cell">
            <span>
                {{ campaignListDtoData.clicks | number }}
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="nano-table-number-cell">
            <span>
                {{ campaignListDtoData.CTR | number }}
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="nano-table-number-cell">
            <span>
                {{ campaignListDtoData.conversions | number }}
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="nano-table-actions-cell">
            <span class="btn-tables-default"
                  (click)="openModal(campaignListDtoData.id)">
                <i class="fa fa-external-link"></i>
            </span>
            <nano-entity-toggle-button #entityToggleButton>
            </nano-entity-toggle-button>

            <nano-campaign-duplicate [campaignId]="campaignListDtoData.id">
            </nano-campaign-duplicate>

            <!--<nano-entity-duplicate-button [entityId]="campaignListDtoData.id"-->
                                          <!--[entityModel]="getCampaignModel()">-->
            <!--</nano-entity-duplicate-button>-->
            <nano-entity-delete-button [entityId]="campaignListDtoData.id"
                                       [entityName]="campaignListDtoData.name"
                                       [entityParentId]="advertiserIoId"
                                       [entityModel]="getCampaignModel()">
            </nano-entity-delete-button>
        </div>
        <div class="nano-table-number-cell">
            <span>
                <i class="fa fa-circle"
                   [class.nano-c-green]="campaignListDtoData.status === 1"
                   [class.nano-c-red]="campaignListDtoData.status === 2"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
        <nano-campaign-edit *ngIf="entityToggleButton.isOpen"
                            [campaignId]="campaignListDtoData.id"
                            [advertiserId]="advertiserId"
                            [advertiserIoId]="advertiserIoId"
                            [insertionOrderTargeting]="insertionOrderTargeting"
                            class="nano-table-preview-cell">
        </nano-campaign-edit>
    </ng-template>
</nano-table>

<div *ngIf="campaignListDto.isLoaded === true"
     class="nano-f-30 nano-f-r">
    <span class="nano-m-a5">
        Statistics are for last 7 days.
    </span>
</div>

<nano-loading-indicator *ngIf="campaignListDto.isLoaded === false"
                        [@flyIn]="'in'">
</nano-loading-indicator>
```

nano-campaign-edit comp:

```
export class NanoCampaignEditComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() advertiserId: string;
@Input() advertiserIoId: string;
@Input() campaignId: string;
@Input() insertionOrderTargeting: string;

@Output() campaignIdChange = new EventEmitter();

@ViewChild('mappingComponent') mappingComponent: NanoMappingComponent;

public campaignDto: CampaignDto;
public entityName = CampaignModel.ENTITY_NAME;

constructor(public campaignModel: CampaignModel) {
}

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getDto();
    this.getDtoData();
}

public onCampaignSave(): void {
    this.campaignIdChange.emit(this.campaignDto.id);
    this.campaignModel.deliveryLimitationConflictCheck(this.campaignDto.id);
}

// retrive campaign which is clicked to be edited
private getDto(): void {
    this.campaignDto = this.campaignModel.getDto(this.campaignId, this.advertiserId, this.advertiserIoId);
}

// retrive all data of campaign which is clicked to be edited
private getDtoData(): void {
    this.campaignModel
        .getDtoData(this.campaignDto)
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

nano-campaing-edit- template: (small part of code)

```
<nano-entity-footer [entityDto]="campaignDto"
                    [entityModel]="campaignModel"
                    [parentForm]="campaignForm"
                    (onEntityDtoSave)="onCampaignSave()">
</nano-entity-footer>
```

nano-table.ts, here is part of code which maybe can be important for this case:

```
export class NanoTableComponent {

  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) template: TemplateRef<any>;

  @Input() columnsArray: Array<NanoTableHeader> = [];
  @Input() isAsync: boolean = false;
  @Input() nanoTable: NanoTable;
  @Input() pageCount: number = 10;
  @Input() pageCountOptions: Array<number> = [5, 10, 20];
  @Input() sortField: string | null = null;
  @Input() sortInverse: boolean = false;
  @Input() useQueryParams: boolean = true;
  @Input() hasExport: boolean = false;


  @Input()
  public set tableList(value: Array<any>) {
      this._tableList = value;
      this.onTableListChange();
  }

  public get tableList(): Array<any> {
      return this._tableList;
  }

  private _tableList: Array<any> = [];

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  }
}
```

nano-table template:

```
<div *ngIf="tableList.length > 0"
 class="nano-table-grid nano-mt-5">

<div class="nano-f-r">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchWord" class="nano-white-smoke-input" placeholder="Search"/>
    <button *ngIf="hasExport === true && isExportInProgress === false"
            type="button"
            class="nano-f-250 nano-white-smoke-button nano-ml-2"
            (click)="exportReport()">
        <span>
            CSV
        </span>
    </button>
    <nano-loading-indicator *ngIf="isExportInProgress === true"
                            class="nano-loading-bar-small nano-loading-bar-overlay nano-f-250 "
                            style="margin-left: 2px"></nano-loading-indicator>
</div>

<div class="nano-table-row nano-table-grid-header">
    <div class="{{column.columnClass}}"
         *ngFor="let column of columnsArray"
         [ngClass]="{'sort-active':sortField === column.columnField}"
         (click)="onSortFieldChange(column.columnField)">
        <span>
            {{column.columnName}}
        </span>
        <i class="fa"
           [class.fa-sort-asc]="sortInverse === true && sortField === column.columnField"
           [class.fa-sort-desc]="sortInverse === false && sortField === column.columnField">
        </i>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="nano-f-c nano-table-row-wrapper"
     *ngFor="let item of getFilteredList()">
    <div class="nano-table-row">
        <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"
                     [ngOutletContext]="{item: item}">
        </ng-template>
    </div>
</div>

<nano-table-footer [pageNumber]="pageNumber"
                   [pageCount]="pageCount"
                   [pageCountOptions]="pageCountOptions"
                   [length]="getLengthForFooter()"
                   (onPageNumberChange)="onPageNumberChange($event)"
                   (onPageCountChange)="onPageCountChange($event)">
</nano-table-footer>
```

Comment: Just a note that I see you emitting an event called campaignIdChange, but I don't see you using it anywhere.

Comment: @canpan14 correct, that emitter is not used anywhere else. I don't know why, I didn't write this code.
 You thing that might be the problem?
I am gonna check that.

Comment: Probably not, I just prefer not to leave code around that is doing nothing. Of course I can only see the code you presented. To help more, would need to see the component code for the table itself to see how it handles some things. Or a link to the package where it came from if it's 3rd party.

Comment: @canpan14 post is updated with nano-table component. 
Note: this nano-table is reusable and this nano-table is used on similar way in the other part of application, with editing some item and saving on same way and there all works fine.

Comment: Awesome, can you also add the code for the initial component.html? The table is reading from the values in that file, want to see how they are being set/altered.

Comment: @canpan14 I updated that is first code component code in the post: list component.html

Comment: I still only see the html for that component, I'm looking for the ts file.

Comment: @canpan14 ok, now it's updated with ts file .Btw Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: No worries. My thoughts right now are around the function onCampaignSave(). I would search the codebase for 'campaignIdChange' and see what is looking for that event. Also I don't know what deliveryLimitationConflictCheck does (in the same function) beyond looking at the name of it. Probably isn't causing a problem but I would like to see it also to confirm it isn't making any changes to the table (again i doubt it is)

Comment: Yes deliveryLimitationConflictCheck() shouldn't be a problem. 
I removed that line of code and bug was still active and all works same as before.

Comment: Thought so, if you search the repo for campaignIdChange. Do you find any other piece of code using it?

Comment: No, here is screenshot of searched result. http://prntscr.com/kakif4

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem. Is it just a duplicate row? Do you have a screenshot of what it's duplicating? Bugs like this are always odd. Basically I think after editing, something is refreshing the data but also adding the new row. After you hit save, if you watch the network does it retrieve all the data for the table again? It's probably doing something to save what you are editing, but if it's also retrieve the data again (which it probably is). Then you would need to look for code that is also trying to put that new entry into the data list after saving.

Comment: Yes, you get new row in table with "new" item(campaign) here is screenshot: http://prntscr.com/kavx69
Also I tried to delete that duplicate and I get error "That Id does not exist" (he can't found that id in db and remove) only on refreshing page that duplicate disappears.
On hit Save in network appear one put request for saving that data.
Ok I am gonna look how he put that new entry into the data list after saving.

Comment: Awesome, so if it isn't pulling a new copy of the data, then something is inserting the new one. Which is fine. Except it isn't removing the old one. So once you find out where it's putting in the new one, just need to also rip out the old one.

Comment: @canpan14 my friend I love you! :D 
I (you) found where was the problem.
That code after saving which should update the list, there was bad If condition instead to check does this campaignID is "New" or "12312321" (really id) he looked is that just campaign. and every time he pass that condition which then try to create new campaig instead to execute else and update current campaign.
Thank you verry much for this hellping. I am really touched. :)
All the best.

Comment: No problem! I've had very similar table issues and always helps to have someone to bounce ideas off of.